# How to move dropdown to rightside end in card header html

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, django-templates

I have a dropdown in card header i need that to be in top right corner how do i set that in my header.I need welcome message in right side of the card header as below image its beside the title

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**What I did:-**

**I added a classes to .card (of bootstrap) with CSS properties of `display: "flex"` `justify-content: "space-between"` and `flex-direction: row`**

reference:- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Style:-

```
<style>
  .card {
    /* Add shadows to create the "card" effect */
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  /* On mouse-over, add a deeper shadow */
  .card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }

  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
</style>
```

Html:-

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding-top: 50px">
      <div class="card d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
        <div
          class="card-header text-center"
          style="font-family: Sans-Serif; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 1.5rem"
        >
          Project Manager Dashboard
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group dropleft">
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
            data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded="false"
          >
            Hi, Drake
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <!-- Dropdown menu links -->
            <a href="{% url 'logout_view' %}"
              ><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Logout</button></a
            >
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSasY.png)

Comment: @ Lokesh Kabra that's not the desired output i wanted bro i needed everything to be same project manager dashboard to be as card header but with your answer the its not showing as card and the button is not displaying completely as in snip right side line

Comment: Not getting you... means what must be done?

Comment: sorry, for late replies

Answer (score 0):

To set it in the top-right corner just use the align property this would align the element to the right.

```html
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding-top: 50px;">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header text-center " style="font-family: Sans-Serif; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:1.5rem">
           Project Manager Dashboard
           
            <div class="btn-group dropright" align="right" >
                  <!-- Dropdown menu links -->
               <a href="{% url 'logout_view' %}"><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Log</button></a>
                  </div>
                  
            <div class="btn-group dropleft">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Hi, Drake
                </button>
            </div>
   
        </div>
```